# How to change a div's content based on current time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to create a dynamically changing coupon pool based on current time. For example price-1 only visible between 9-10 am, price-2 between 10-11, etc.

```html
<div class="pricepool">
  <div class="price-1">
  50% COUPON CODE...
  </div>
  <div class="price-2">
  30% COUPON CODE...
  </div>
  <div class="price-3">
  70% COUPON CODE...
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript and jquery solutions both perfect for me.

Comment: Side note : Please also check this server side, someone can just modify this to always get the most % off.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: A you want to use server time or browser time to do that?

Comment: As @GillBates noted, having all three coupon codes in your markup will allow savvy users to always insert the 70% coupon code by copy-pasting it from page source. **Do not do this in `javascript`**. Do it server-side.

Comment: http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now a simple ajax call to it should return the current time.    $.ajax({
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: 'http://timeapi.org/utc/now.json',
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result.dateString);
    }
});

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047529/display-html-content-between-defined-hours-mon-to-friday

Answer (score 0):

If simple to understand code than should be something like this:

```
setInterval(function(){
   var d = new Date();
   var currentHour = d.getHours(); // from 0 to 23 
   $(".pricepool > div").hide();
   if (currentHour > 15) {
      $(".pricepool > div.price-3").show();
   } else if (currentHour > 9) {
      $(".pricepool > div.price-2").show();
   } else {
      $(".pricepool > div.price-1").show();
   }
}, 10000);
```

Specify if statements according to your needs.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now a simple ajax call to it should return the `$.ajax({
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: 'http://timeapi.org/utc/now.json',
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result.dateString);
    }
});`
instead of alert you can use yours logic. Also you should send this on apprppriate interval( depends on your resource capabilites)